# remote data fetching inside model object in objective c using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, model-view-controller, afnetworking-2

In all of my iOS application I use this approach to respect MVC, I want to be sure that my implementation is correct and respects the best practices and the MVC design pattern :

Singleton of AFNetworking acting as API for network calls:

MyAPI.h :

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface MyAPI : AFHTTPSessionManager

+(MyAPI *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

MyAPI.m :

```
#pragma mark - Singleton

+(MyAPI*)sharedInstance
{
 static MyAPI *sharedInstance = nil;
 static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
 dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[MyAPI alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kROOT_URL]];
});
  return sharedInstance;
}
```

Model User that uses the singleton to fecth the data of user (is that good as implementation ?):

User.h

```
 @interface User : NSObject

 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *userId;
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *email;
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *password;


-(id) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionay;

 +(BOOL) isConnected;
 +(void) disconnect;
 +(NSString *) idOfConnectedUser;
 +(User *) connectedUser;

 +(void) loginWith : (NSString *) email andPassword :(NSString *) password complete:(void(^)(id result, NSError *error))block;
 +(void) searchUsersFrom : (NSString *) countryCode withName :(NSString *) name andLevel:(NSString *) levelCode complete: (void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) block;
 +(void) signup:(void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) block;
 +(void) getUserFriends:(void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) block;

@end
```

User.m

```
  [......]

 +(void) loginWith : (NSString *) email andPassword :(NSString *) password complete: (void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) block
 {

 __block NSString * result ;

NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": email, @"password": password};

[[MyAPI sharedInstance] POST:@"auth/" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
{

    if([responseObject objectForKey:@"id"])
    { 
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(NSDictionary*) responseObject forKey:USER_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        result = [responseObject objectForKey:@"id"];
    }
    else
    {
        result = nil ;
    }


    if (block) block(result, nil);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
{
     if (block) block(nil, error);
}];

}
[.....]
```

LoginController.m :

```
-(void)loginButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [......]

    [ User loginWith:text andPassword:text complete:^(id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (result)
         {
             [APPDELEGATE start];
         }
         else
         {
          // ERROR
         }
       }];

   }
```

So does my implementation respects the MCV and follows the best practices and how can I improve it if not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Singletons**: You might want to avoid using singletons, it'll help you to improve your API design and make code more testable. Also, in case of `User`, imagine you will want to support changing user (logout/guest user/etc). With current approach, you will be limited to sending a `NSNotification` because everyone who uses `connectedUser` can not know that underlying reference has changed.

**ActiveRecord**:
What you did with your model `User` that is capable of performing networking is somewhat similar to [active record approach](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) which might not scale so well when you model becomes more complicated and the number of actions it can perform increases. Consider separating those into pure model and services that actually perform networking (or whatever else you will need in the future).

**Model Serialisation**:
Consider encapsulating model & network response serialisation logic into a separate class (e.g. `LoginResponse` that among other things points to a `User`) frameworks like [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) make it much easier.

**MVC**: from my experience in iOS MVC might not be the most optimal approach for anything but simple apps. With MVC tendency is to put put all the logic into your `ViewController` making it very big and hard to maintain. Consider other patterns such as [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

All in all I understand that it is hard to learn all the new technologies at once, but you can definitely start by making sure each class performs one thing and one thing only: Model does not do networking or persisting to the disk, API client doesn't deserialise each response or saves data to `NSUserDefaults`, view controller doesn't do anything except for listening to user events (button taps etc). This alone would make your code much easier to reason about and to follow if a new developer would be introduced to your codebase.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I dont have anything to say about your MVC(Model–view–controller) correct?

I just want to add something that may be useful approach avoiding unwanted crashes..

First is under

```
[[MyAPI sharedInstance] POST:@"auth/" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) 
{
    if([responseObject objectForKey:@"id"])
    { 
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(NSDictionary*) responseObject forKey:USER_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        result = [responseObject objectForKey:@"id"];
    }
    else
    {
        result = nil ;
    }
}];
```

it is always possible for so many reason to mention that the `reponseObject` could be `nil` and therefore object dont have the key `@"id"` and will lead to error(crash in worst case). i have this code i dont know if this can be considered as best practice but here it is:

```
if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Log: Response is of class NSArray");
}
else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Log: Response is of class NSDictionary");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Log: Kind of class is not supported");
}
```

This example restricts other kind of class especially `[NSNull class]`

Second in line:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": email, @"password": password};
```

by checking `email` and `password` first before assigning to `NSDictionary`, setting nil to NSDictionary will cause crash.

Third is line:

```
if (block) block(result, nil);
```

`block` returns `void` from your implementation. Is this working? Sorry for asking i haven't tried `if-statement` with a block like this..

`complete: (void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) block`

`void` in this is the returning value of your block, or i'm wrong.. hmm..

`if (block)` only checks if the `block` block exist, so intead of checking it (which we are sure that is existing)..

maybe you want to check the `result` instead...

`if (result != nil) block(result, nil);` is the right statement

the reason behind is:

```
if (result != nil) // will return NONE nil value only
{
    block(result, nil); 
}

// else will not set things to the block

//or maybe just 

block(result, nil); // which will allow the 'block(nil, nil);' and under your implementation

[ User loginWith:text andPassword:text complete:^(id result, NSError *error)
{
     if (result)
     {
         [APPDELEGATE start];
     }
     else if (result == nil & error == nil)
     {
         // NO objectForKey @"id"
     }
     else
     {
         // ERROR
     }
}];
```

while under `failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)` simply `block(nil, error);`

Comment: just a little note, `if([responseObject objectForKey:@"id"])` will evaluate to `NO` if `responseObject` is `nil` so no crash there if I understood your concern correctly. 

Besides, checking for the type of the data is something you might do during development, but not in production when API is established: too much of a defensive coding in my opinion.

Comment: and the original code is correct in a sense that you have to check if `block != nil` (can be abbreviated to `if (block)`) and call it only after you're sure you have a valid pointer.

Comment: @SashZats, i understand.. But he is asking for best practices, Isn't it best to check everything before production? and there is no such thing "too much defensive coding", thats what you call *error handling*  and foreseeing possible error is a bad thing? "system reliability" and "all most" bug free system is good right?

Comment: and about `if (block)` the statement only check if block do exist, and maybe you think it is not? My answer is talking about the return value of the block.. there, i've edited my answer for clearance.. Cheers. :)

Comment: Networking does fail fairly often so this is something I would defend against. Now imagine working against Facebook API v X.X when all of a sudden it changes the returning data type. This doesn't really happen in production. As for the result I don't see anything fishy except for `nil` case in success, I would probably add a manually created `NSError` (e.g. response malformed…)

Comment: @SashZats, you should have posted it as an answer instead of downvoting my answer and commenting some useful information.. and i will not change my `kindOfClass` thing.. :) that error handling saved me for so many times.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I though it is irrelevant and the question is more on the architectural best practices. Hope it didn't affect you too much Cheers!

Comment: Don't worry, it is okay besides I love having this kind of conversation, this kind of thing makes us more knowledgable on our field.. right? :) Cheers, brother.. (highfive) :D